# How to set proxy authentication in windows 7 for updating texlive packages?

Tags: texlive

Hello Tex friends I am trying to update my latex packages over through my proxy server,

we have a proxy server with authentication

as e.g proxy=202.141.80.80, port=3128, username=abc, password=bcd,

when I type as `tlmgr update --list` I was not able to update the packages in windows 7

I already set an environment variable to set http proxy

as `set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port`

`set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@proxy:port`

`set FTP_PROXY=ftp://username:password@proxy:port`

When i type in command promt as `tlmgr update --list` it give as

`Proxy must be specified as absolute URI; 'HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:port' is not at C:/texlive/2018/tlpkg/TeXlive/TLDownload.pm line 45`

Comment: is the proxy address correct (shouldn't it be 4 sets of numbers)?

Comment: Yes, it is 4 sets of number i wrongly written here, i corrected in my question @albert

Answer (score 1):

My problems has been solved by typing this command in windows command prompt

`set http_proxy=http://username:password@202.141.80.80:3128`

texlive is able to update package successfully through proxy authentication under windows 7.